# При выборе чекбокса заносить его значение в массив

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Есть такой код html:

```js
var checked = [];
                        $(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
                          var chbx = $(this);
                          var seq = chbx.parent().parent().attr('data-seq');
                          var sel_list_seq = chbx.parent().parent().children('.sel_seq_list');
                          if (seq == 1) {
                            if (chbx.is(':checked')) {
                              checked.push(chbx.val());
                            } else {
                              var index = checked.indexOf(chbx.val());
                              if (index != -1)
                                checked[index] = null;
                              checked = checked.filter(item => item != null);
                            }
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(checked));
                          }
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qwestion_40" class="question_item">
  <b>Вопрос 2 (3 правильных варианта ответа - последовательность 5,2,3)</b>
  <div id="8" data-max="3" data-seq="1">
    <input name="qw_40[seq]" value="1" type="hidden">
    <input name="qw_40[cta]" value="3" type="hidden">
    <div><input id="answer_40_57" value="57" class="chbx" name="qw_40[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_40_57"><span></span>Ответ 1</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_40_58" value="58" class="chbx" name="qw_40[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_40_58"><span></span>Ответ 2 (true)</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_40_59" value="59" class="chbx" name="qw_40[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_40_59"><span></span>Ответ 3 (true)</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_40_60" value="60" class="chbx" name="qw_40[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_40_60"><span></span>Ответ 4</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_40_61" value="61" class="chbx" name="qw_40[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_40_61"><span></span>Ответ 5 (true)</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="qwestion_42" class="question_item">
    <b>Вопрос 4 (2 ответа)</b>
    <div id="8" data-max="2" data-seq="1">
        <input name="qw_42[seq]" value="1" type="hidden">
        <input name="qw_42[cta]" value="2" type="hidden">
    <div><input id="answer_42_64" value="64" class="chbx" name="qw_42[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_42_64"><span></span>Ответ 1 (true)</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_42_65" value="65" class="chbx" name="qw_42[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_42_65"><span></span>Ответ 2 (true)</label></div>
    <div><input id="answer_42_66" value="66" class="chbx" name="qw_42[]" type="checkbox">&nbsp;<label for="answer_42_66"><span></span>Ответ 3</label></div></div></div>
```

Скажите, как мне при выборе `checkbox`, заносить его значение в массив или например в скрытое поле `input`. Проблема в том, что мне нужно заносить последовательность выбранных `checkbox`. А значит, если пользователь передумал и какой-то `checkbox` отменил, его значение должно удаляться из массива выбранных.
Пытался таким кодом, но он не удаляет убранный пользователем `checkbox` из последовательности.

UPDATE
Данный код, написанный пользователем Igor работает, но он все значения пишет в один массив (со всех блоков с чекбоксами), а мне нужно под каждый из блоков checkbox свой массив создать, чтобы данные в нем сохранялись независимо друг от друга.

Answer (score 1):

```
var checked = {};
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var chbx = $(this);
  var seq = chbx.parent().parent().attr('data-seq');
  if (seq == 1) {
    if (chbx.is(':checked')) {
      checked[chbx.val()] = true;
    } else {
      delete checked[chbx.val()];
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(checked)));
  }
});
```

*Update*

```
var checked = {};
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var chbx = $(this);
  var id = chbx.closest(".question_item").attr("id");
  if (!checked[id])
    checked[id] = [];
  var chArr = checked[id];
  var seq = chbx.parent().parent().attr('data-seq');
  if (seq == 1) {
    if (chbx.is(':checked')) {
      chArr.push(chbx.val());
    } else {
      var index = chArr.indexOf(chbx.val());
      if (index != -1)
        chArr[index] = null;
      chArr = chArr.filter(item => item != null);
    }
    checked[id] = chArr;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(checked));
  }
});
```

> на странице может быть несколько групп с чекбоксами, в которых нужно
>   учитывать последовательность. Как для каждой свой массив сделать?

Да, для каждой свой массив. Все эти массивы поместите в один объект как свойства с ключами вытекающими из `id` контейнеров.

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо за ответ. Но у вас значения в массиве располагаются в порядке возрастания, а нужно именно в том порядке, в котором кликал пользователь. И еще такая проблема у меня: на странице может быть несколько групп с чекбоксами, в которых нужно учитывать последовательность. Как для каждой свой массив сделать?

Comment: Да, с последовательностью теперь все ОК, а вот как быть с тем, если у меня несколько групп чекбоксов на странице - в предыдущем комменте писал?)) Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: "Да, для каждой свой массив. Все эти массивы поместите в один объект как свойства с ключами вытекающими из id контейнеров."
Не совсем понял как? Просто у меня суть такая: есть тестирование, в некоторых вопросах нужно указать именно правильную последовательность. Я вот и хотел под каждый вопрос - свой массив с последовательностями и потом их запулить например в скрытый input и отправить а на php потом разобрать и сравнить? не?

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне под каждый блок checkbox свой массив замутить?